# DefaultSocialAccountAdapter overrriding pre_social_login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to verify email address before login or singup via google account.

I have below code:

```
from django.http import Http404
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
    email_domain = sociallogin.account.user.email.split('@')[1].lower()
    if email_domain == 'mysuperdomain.org':
        print email_domain
        pass
```

It is working fine when I'm login(google account already exist in Django) but when trying first time singup i have err below:

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/
SocialAccount has no user.

Any wisdom will be most appreciated.

Thanks,

J

ok have some progress with below signal code:

```
    from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
    from django.http import Http404
    from auth.settings import ALLOWED_DOMAIN


    def email_allowed(user, **kwargs):
        email_domain = user.email.split('@')[1].lower()
        if not email_domain == ALLOWED_DOMAIN:
            raise Http404

    user_signed_up.connect(email_allowed)
```

but still need to take some action to prevent adding user account when domain is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the "SocialAccount has no user" error, try using `sociallogin.user` instead of `sociallogin.account.user`. Furthermore, you may want to put the email validation logic in the `clean_email` method of a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help @pennersr.

I ended up with belowe code:

```
class KcSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
    email_domain = sociallogin.user.email.split('@')[1].lower()
    if not email_domain == ALLOWED_DOMAIN:
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponse(sociallogin.user.email + ' is not valid memeber of ' +ALLOWED_DOMAIN))
    else:
        pass
```